# make all the fileds are required in html

Tags: html

Is it possible by default make all the fileds in a div class as required fileds. I have a form and inside the form i have a div class.. why i am using the div class is by defalut the div class is hidden and when i clicked on some check box it will be visible.  SO i need all the elements in the div class should be required filed. I was trying required="required" on all the elements but it is not working. Any one has idea?
  Here is my html

```
                      <div class="downtime" id="downtime" style="display: none" >
    <label> name </label>
    <input required="required" type="text" name="name><br>
    <label> age </label>
    <input required="required type="text" name="age><br>
    </div>
                  </form>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting) - probably the greatest tool at any coder's disposal. (It's even on Stack Overflow!)

```
<div class="downtime" id="downtime" style="display: none" >
<label> name </label>
<input required="required" type="text" name="name><br>
<label> age </label>
<input required="required type="text" name="age><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Attributes are red and their values are blue. So it should look more like this:

```
<div class="downtime" id="downtime" style="display: none" >
<label> name </label>
<input required="required" type="text" name="name" /><br>
<label> age </label>
<input required="required" type="text" name="age" /><br>
</div>
</form>
```

and FYI the `required` attribute doesn't need a value:

```
<input type="text" name="age" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required>
```

and

```
<input name="age" required>
```

Just writing "**required**" make your fields as required. It works only in **HTML5**. So put  it before html tag starts.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use html5 you can do it with required(this only works on browsers that support html5), if not use a jquery plugin for validation like this:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/